# Glfm and vulkan window not working even if compiler works fine

Tags: c++, vulkan

I made this simple program to test my vulkan and glfm setup. I get no compiler errors. Instead it pops up in the cmd and says "Failed". I followed this tutorial to setup everything but he did not show his code so I had to puzzle some pieces together and that is probably the error here.

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE
#include <glm/vec4.hpp>
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp>

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    // Initialize GLFW
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Create a GLFW window
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Vulkan Window", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Create a Vulkan instance (empty parameters for simplicity)
    VkInstance instance;
    if (vkCreateInstance(nullptr, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        std::cerr << "Failed" << std::endl;
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Main loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Perform rendering with Vulkan
        // ...

    }

    // Clean up resources
    vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to pass a valid `VkInstanceCreateInfo` structure to `vkCreateInstance`. https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap4.html#VUID-vkCreateInstance-pCreateInfo-parameter